# При изменении значения атрибутa из метода ошибка: PLS-00363: expression 'SELF.xxx' cannot be used as an assignment target

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Пробую создать объект с некоторыми атрибутами. Он имеет метод, который должен проверять актуальное значение в БД и присваивать его атрибуту сущности объекта. Но не знаю, возможно ли это.

Когда компилирую следующий код, то получаю ошибку:

```
create table params (name unique, value) as
    select 'param'||rownum, 'value'||rownum
    from dual connect by level<=3
/
create or replace type paramT as object (
    name varchar2 (8), value varchar2 (8),
    member function verify return paramT 
)
/
create or replace type body paramT as 
    member function verify return paramT is
        v varchar2 (8);
    begin 
        select value into v
        from params 
        where name = self.name;
        self.value := v;
        return self;
    end;    
end;
/
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
8/9      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
8/14     PLS-00363: expression 'SELF.VALUE' cannot be used as an
         assignment target
```

Думаю, что это скорее концептуальная проблема, и мне это не очень понятно.

Почему возникает эта ошибка, и как быть в этом случае?

---

<sub>Схожий вопрос [Can I assign value to object attribute from the object method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64375742) от участника [@Joaquin Gavilan Rojas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10665285/joaquin-gavilan-rojas)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/64375742

Answer (score 2):

Из оф. документации гл. [Declaring SELF Parameters in Member Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adobj/object-methods.html#GUID-0A7901B9-EFB4-4243-B01B-2325A3706F6E):

> SELF is always the first parameter passed to the method.
>
> In member functions, if SELF is not declared, its parameter mode defaults to IN.
>
> In member procedures, if SELF is not declared, its parameter mode defaults to IN OUT. The default behavior does not include the NOCOPY compiler hint.

В функциях объекта неявный параметр `SELF` по умолчанию `IN`, то есть не может быть изменён.

В данном случае, достаточно изменить функцию на процедуру. Как в этом примере:

```
create or replace type paramT as object (
    name varchar2 (8), value varchar2 (8),
    member procedure verify  
)
/
create or replace type body paramT as 
    member procedure verify is
        v varchar2 (8);
    begin 
        select value into v
        from params 
        where name = self.name;
        self.value := v;
    end;    
end;
/
```

Так проверить:

```
var rc refcursor
declare
    p paramT := paramT ('param2', 'undef');
begin 
    p.verify;
    open :rc for select p param from dual;  
end;
/

PARAM(NAME, VALUE)
--------------------------------
PARAMT('param2', 'value2')
```